# Robot Framework: Do something after the execution ends using a library as a listener

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

I am trying to gather the files: **output.xml, report.html and log.html** when the whole execution ends.

I can use a listener for this purpose but I want to avoid write a line like:

**robot --listener "SomeListener.py" YourTestSuite.robot**

Then, I looked at the documentation and I found that I can use a Test Library as a Listener and import it in my Test Suite, for example:

```
class SomeLibrary(object):
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2 # or 3
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL" # or TEST SUITE

    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self

    def start_suite(self, data, result):
        pass

    def close(self):
        pass
```

My problem is that the **close** method is called when the library goes out of the scope. So, I cannot gather the report files because they don't exist in that moment and I receive an Error. I also tried with the method:

```
def report_file(self, path):
    pass
```

But, nothing happens, I guess that it could be because a Library as a Listener cannot use this methods from the **Listener API** or because the file is still not created.

Any idea about How can I gather those files using a library as a Listener?
I am open to ideas or suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Listener specification actually specifies three methods that are triggered when the three files are generated:

```
startSuite
endSuite
startTest
endTest
startKeyword
endKeyword
logMessage
message
outputFile
logFile
reportFile
debugFile
```

Have a look at the last 4 ones, which should be helpful. For more details look at the listener API specification. [4.3.3   Listener interface methods](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id765)

Comment: Hi, I know that I can use those methods the problem was the scope when I was using a Library as a Listener.
I resolved the problem using a wrapper that executes robot with some predefined parameters.

Comment: Good to hear that you've been able to overcome the issue. Using a listener as a library allows for more scope options which can be confusing. Loading a listener via the command line --listener argument puts it in the global scope and should clear those issues for you.